# How to load checkpoints across different versions of pytorch (1.3.1 and 1.6.x) using ppc64le and x86?

Tags: pytorch, ppc64le

As I outlined here I am stuck using old versions of pytorch and torchvision due to hardware e.g. using ppc64le IBM architectures.

For this reason, I am having issues when sending and receiving checkpoints between different computers, clusters and my personal mac. I wonder if there is any way to load models in a way to avoid this issue? e.g. perhaps saving models in with a old and new format when using 1.6.x. Of course for the 1.3.1 to 1.6.x is impossible but at leat I was hoping something would work.

Any advice? Of course my ideal solution is that I don't have to worry about it and I can always load and save my checkpoints and everything I usually pickle uniformly across all my hardware.

---

The first error I got was a zip jit error:

```
RuntimeError: /home/miranda9/data/f.pt is a zip archive (did you mean to use torch.jit.load()?)
```

so I used that (and other pickle libraries):

```
# %%
import torch
from pathlib import Path


def load(path):
    import torch
    import pickle
    import dill

    path = str(path)
    try:
        db = torch.load(path)
        f = db['f']
    except Exception as e:
        db = torch.jit.load(path)
        f = db['f']
        #with open():
        # db = pickle.load(open(path, "r+"))
        # db = dill.load(open(path, "r+"))
        #raise ValueError(f'FAILED: {e}')
    return db, f

p = "~/data/f.pt"
path = Path(p).expanduser()

db, f = load(path)

Din, nb_examples = 1, 5
x = torch.distributions.Normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0).sample(sample_shape=(nb_examples, Din))

y = f(x)

print(y)
print('Success!\a')
```

but I get complains of different pytorch versions which I am forced to use:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hal_pg.py", line 27, in <module>
    db, f = load(path)
  File "hal_pg.py", line 16, in load
    db = torch.jit.load(path)
  File "/home/miranda9/.conda/envs/wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/__init__.py", line 239, in load
    cpp_module = torch._C.import_ir_module(cu, f, map_location, _extra_files)
RuntimeError: version_number <= kMaxSupportedFileFormatVersion INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at /opt/anaconda/conda-bld/pytorch-base_1581395437985/work/caffe2/serialize/inline_container.cc:131, please report a bug to PyTorch. Attempted to read a PyTorch file with version 3, but the maximum supported version for reading is 1. Your PyTorch installation may be too old. (init at /opt/anaconda/conda-bld/pytorch-base_1581395437985/work/caffe2/serialize/inline_container.cc:131)
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) + 0xbc (0x7fff7b527b9c in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: caffe2::serialize::PyTorchStreamReader::init() + 0x1d98 (0x7fff1d293c78 in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
frame #2: caffe2::serialize::PyTorchStreamReader::PyTorchStreamReader(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) + 0x88 (0x7fff1d2950d8 in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
frame #3: torch::jit::import_ir_module(std::shared_ptr<torch::jit::script::CompilationUnit>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, c10::optional<c10::Device>, std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&) + 0x64 (0x7fff1e624664 in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x70e210 (0x7fff7c0ae210 in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #5: <unknown function> + 0x28efc4 (0x7fff7bc2efc4 in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
<omitting python frames>
frame #26: <unknown function> + 0x25280 (0x7fff84b35280 in /lib64/libc.so.6)
frame #27: __libc_start_main + 0xc4 (0x7fff84b35474 in /lib64/libc.so.6)
```

any ideas how to make everything consistent across the clusters? I can't even open the pickle files.

---

maybe this is just impossible with the current pytorch version I am forced to use :(

```
RuntimeError: version_number <= kMaxSupportedFileFormatVersion INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at /opt/anaconda/conda-bld/pytorch-base_1581395437985/work/caffe2/serialize/inline_container.cc:131, please report a bug to PyTorch. Attempted to read a PyTorch file with version 3, but the maximum supported version for reading is 1. Your PyTorch installation may be too old. (init at /opt/anaconda/conda-bld/pytorch-base_1581395437985/work/caffe2/serialize/inline_container.cc:131)
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) + 0xbc (0x7fff83ba7b9c in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning_wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: caffe2::serialize::PyTorchStreamReader::init() + 0x1d98 (0x7fff25993c78 in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning_wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
frame #2: caffe2::serialize::PyTorchStreamReader::PyTorchStreamReader(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) + 0x88 (0x7fff259950d8 in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning_wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
frame #3: torch::jit::import_ir_module(std::shared_ptr<torch::jit::script::CompilationUnit>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, c10::optional<c10::Device>, std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&) + 0x64 (0x7fff26d24664 in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning_wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x70e210 (0x7fff8472e210 in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning_wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #5: <unknown function> + 0x28efc4 (0x7fff842aefc4 in /home/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning_wmlce-v1.7.0-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
<omitting python frames>
frame #23: <unknown function> + 0x25280 (0x7fff8d335280 in /lib64/libc.so.6)
frame #24: __libc_start_main + 0xc4 (0x7fff8d335474 in /lib64/libc.so.6)
```

using code:

```
from pathlib import Path

import torch

path = '/home/miranda9/data/dataset/'
path = Path(path).expanduser() / 'fi_db.pt'
path = str(path)

# db = torch.load(path)
# torch.jit.load(path)
db = torch.jit.load(str(path))

print(db)
```

---

related links:

- [How to load checkpoints across different versions of pytorch (1.3.1 and 1.6.x) using ppc64le and x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141188/how-to-load-checkpoints-across-different-versions-of-pytorch-1-3-1-and-1-6-x-u)
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-load-checkpoints-across-different-versions-of-pytorch-1-3-1-and-1-6-x-using-ppc64le-and-x86/97829
- related gitissue: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/43766
- reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/jvza7v/how_to_load_checkpoints_across_different_versions/

Comment: Have you considered using virtual environments, [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? It's a good practice when working with Python projects. That way you can have different versions in the same machine.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 of course. In fact the HPC I am using doesn't work without them. I am using an IBM cloned env. I loaded it with `module load wmlce/1.7.0-py3.7`. How was that suppose to fix things? The versions of pytorch are fixed because of the hardware archiecture ppc64le. So I don't know if there is any benefit in using different version of pytorch in my case (since its likely impossible)

Answer (score 3):

I believe what the developers intend is passing a flag for saving as a pickle. Just a default behavior change.

For previously checkpointed files reload the zip file saved weights in the newer env(with pytorch>=1.6), and then checkpoint again as a pickle (no need to re-train);

update your code and add flag from next time

[Deprecation from ver 1.6](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v1.6.0) :

> We have switched torch.save to use a zip file-based format by default
> rather than the old Pickle-based format. torch.load has retained the
> ability to load the old format, but use of the new format is
> recommended. The new format is:
>
> more friendly for inspection and building tooling for manipulating the
> save files fixes a long-standing issue wherein serialization
> (**getstate**, **setstate**) functions on Modules that depended on
> serialized Tensor values were getting the wrong data the same as the
> TorchScript serialization format, making serialization more consistent
> across PyTorch

Usage is as follows:

```
m = MyMod()
torch.save(m.state_dict(), 'mymod.pt') # Saves a zipfile to mymod.pt
```

To use the old format, pass the flag `_use_new_zipfile_serialization=False`

```
m = MyMod()
torch.save(m.state_dict(), 'mymod.pt', _use_new_zipfile_serialization=False) # Saves pickle
```

Comment: For a checkpoint saved with previous version, how do I load it in new version of pytorch?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ideal solution, but it works for transferring checkpoints from newer versions to older versions.

I also use ppc64le and face the same problems. It is possible to save the model in text format which can be read by any PyTorch version. I have PyTorch v1.3.0 installed on the ppc64le machine, and v1.7.0 on my notebook (which doesn't need to have a graphics card).

Step 1. Save model via the newer PyTorch version

```
def save_model_txt(model, path):
    fout = open(path, 'w')
    for k, v in model.state_dict().items():
        fout.write(str(k) + '\n')
        fout.write(str(v.tolist()) + '\n')
    fout.close()
```

Prior to saving, I load the model like so

```
checkpoint = torch.load(path, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint, strict=False)
```

Step 2. Transfer the text file

Step 3. Load the text file in old PyTorch

```
def load_model_txt(model, path):
    data_dict = {}
    fin = open(path, 'r')
    i = 0
    odd = 1
    prev_key = None
    while True:
        s = fin.readline().strip()
        if not s:
            break
        if odd:
            prev_key = s
        else:
            print('Iter', i)
            val = eval(s)
            if type(val) != type([]):
                data_dict[prev_key] = torch.FloatTensor([eval(s)])[0]
            else:
                data_dict[prev_key] = torch.FloatTensor(eval(s))
            i += 1
        odd = (odd + 1) % 2

    # Replace existing values with loaded

    print('Loading...')
    own_state = model.state_dict()
    print('Items:', len(own_state.items()))
    for k, v in data_dict.items():
        if not k in own_state:
            print('Parameter', k, 'not found in own_state!!!')
        else:
            try:
                own_state[k].copy_(v)
            except:
                print('Key:', k)
                print('Old:', own_state[k])
                print('New:', v)
                sys.exit(0)
    print('Model loaded')
```

The model must be initialized before loading. The empty model is passed into the function.

**Limitations**

If your model state_dict contains something else than (str: torch.Tensor) values, this method will not work. You can inspect your state_dict contents with

```
for k, v in model.state_dict().items():
    ...
```

Read these for understanding:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_and_loading_models_for_inference.html

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-load-part-of-pre-trained-model/1113

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer by @maxim velikanov, I created a separate OrderedDict where the keys are the same as the original state dict for the model, but each tensor value is converted to a list.

This OrderedDict is them dumped into a JSON file.

```py
def save_model_json(model, path):
    actual_dict = OrderedDict()
    for k, v in model.state_dict().items():
      actual_dict[k] = v.tolist()
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
      json.dump(actual_dict, f)
```

The loader can then load the file as a JSON, and each list / integer will be converted back to a Tensor before having its values copied into the original state dict.

```py
def load_model_json(model, path):
  data_dict = OrderedDict()
  with open(path, 'r') as f:
    data_dict = json.load(f)    
  own_state = model.state_dict()
  for k, v in data_dict.items():
    print('Loading parameter:', k)
    if not k in own_state:
      print('Parameter', k, 'not found in own_state!!!')
    if type(v) == list or type(v) == int:
      v = torch.tensor(v)
    own_state[k].copy_(v)
  model.load_state_dict(own_state)
  print('Model loaded')
```

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar issue when loading processed data. I previously saved data in torch 1.8 as 'xxx.pt', but loaded it in torch 1.2. I couldn't succefullly load it even by torch.jit.load(). My only solution is to save the data again in the older version.